# Trying to get property of non-object - Laravel Form

Tags: forms, laravel, many-to-many

I am creating a form with a many-many relationship. I have a posts table and an activities table. There is a many to many link using pivot table. I am creating a form to add one or more activities to the posts. I am receiving an 'ErrorException' - Trying to get property of non-object. I cannot understand why this is not working.

I would be grateful for any assistance you can offer me.

My relevant code is below.

```
//Posts/create.blade.php

{!!Form::open(['action' => 'PostController@store','method' => 'POST',    'class'=>'form-group'])!!}
  {{Form::bsText('title','',['placeholder' => 'Trip Name'])}}
  {{Form::bsTextarea('body','',['placeholder' => 'Trip Description'])}}
  {{Form::bsSubmit('submit')}}



  {{Form::label('activities', 'Activity:') }}
  <select class="form-control select2-multi" name="activities" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach($activities as $activity)
    <option value="{{ $activity->id }}">{{ $activity->activity_name}}
    </option>
    @endforeach

  </select>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

// PostsController

```
public function create()
    {
      $activities = Activity::all();
        return view('posts.create')->withActivities($activities);
        $posts = Post::all();

    }
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Create a new post using the request data
    // Save it to the database
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',

    ]);
  $post = Post::create([
    'title' =>request('title'),
    'body' =>request('body'),
    'user_id' => auth()->id(),
    'activity_id' => id()
  ]);



    // And then redirect to somewhere in  application
    return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
}
```

Comment: Where do you get that exception? On which line?

Comment: What does `id()` mean in `'activity_id' => id()`?

Comment: Thank you for your comments!

What does id() mean in 'activity_id' => id()?
I realise now that that is a mistake.

I get the error from the blade at the </select> point - shows line 30 in the create.blade.php. So I assume that it is an error in the form or controller. Am I right in assuming that I need to pass activity table's id (as per the users table) into: 

```
 $post = Post::create([
    'title' =>request('title'),
    'body' =>request('body'),
    'user_id' => auth()->id(),
  ]);

Comment: try `dd()` to check response what are you getting by your query?

Comment: I have dd($activitiies) on the create method but I am not able to dd($post) on the store method. It shares the index's method route. 

| GET|HEAD  | posts| posts.index|PostController@index|         
| POST           | posts| posts.store| PostController@store

Answer (score 0):

This error throw only when you have empty variable but you point in blade file to render / display for browser. Or if you retrieve records from DB then add findOrFail in query to prevent those kind of issues. Thank you.

Comment: He only uses the `all()` method. That shouldn't crash.

Comment: Actually he is doing couple of things wrong as per my assumption. He needs to put $request instead of request() and then in post create method 
 he put id() where this coming from in code ?

Comment: I know that a solution with the `$request` variable is more elegant, but it is not causing the issue. So that is not an answer to the question

Comment: When I dd on the create method - so checking that the 

$activities = Activity::all(); 

I do receive the data as you would expect.